# Getting current system time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

How do I get current system time in SQL Server?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [GETDATE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) function

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 7):

[CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751.aspx) is ANSI compliant and equivalent to GETDATE()

Otherwise, you have a [plethora of functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#DateandTimeFunctions) as mentioned in SQL Server 2008 BOL here (with link for SQL Server 2005 too).

I think marc_s might have missed 1 or 2 ;-)

Comment: well, except for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, I think I covered all the revelant ones, don't you agree? :-)

Answer (score 6):

Since SQL Server 2000, we also had:

- [`GETUTCDATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258904(SQL.80).aspx) to get the UTC (Universal Time) - no dependant on local time zone settings

SQL Server 2008 (the OP didn't specify his exact version) also has:

- [`SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677334.aspx) to get the current local time including the timezone offset as DATETIMEOFFSET data type (new to SQL Server 2008)

SQL Server 2008 also offers `SYSDATETIME()` and `SYSUTCDATETIME()` with more accuracy (down to 100ns) than `GETDATE()` or `GETUTCDATE()` in previous versions (accuracy: 3.33ms).

Answer (score 0):

dater datetime default getupdate()
dater it is an name of column
datetime it is an datatype 
default it is an assign current system date and time

but the inserting a column data we firstly mention the column names
i.e. insert into table_name(column names) values(that mention in column names);

Comment: This does not answer the question 'How do I get current system time in SQL Server?'